# Get part of array and append the values

Tags: php, arrays

How to get part of array and append the values ?

I have an test array

```
Array
(
    [name] => test
    [sex] => male
    [contests] => 
    [polls] => 
    [quotes] => 
    [spouse] => ,57
    [father] => ,55
    [mother] => ,56
    [brother] => ,1,3
)
```

I want to take array elements from spouse to brother and get appended all values to string .

```
 $test = ',57,55,56,1,3'
```

Is it possible to done with array functions in `PHP` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way

```
$test = implode('', array_splice($array, 0, 5));
```

Getting position of key in assosiative array (not best solution but working)

```
 $keys = array_keys($array);
 $from_index = array_search('spouse', $keys);
 $to_index = array_search('brother', $keys);
 $offset = $to_index - $from_index + 1;
 $test = implode('', array_splice($array, $from_index, $offset));
```

Comment: It is possible to index as variables as `array_splice($array, 'spouse', 'brother');`

Comment: No you cant do like that, array_splice (array, numeric key index, offset). But you can get position of keys in array do aray_splice

Comment: Is there any way to do like that ?